# Is it possible to classify Wi-Fi Security Level without connect to Wi-Fi

Tags: wifi, wireless

Is it possible to classify Wi-Fi Security Level (such as Secure, Non-secure, etc.) without connect to Wi-Fi.

I don't know is it possible, but if not, can we still classify Wi-Fi security level when connect to Wi-Fi?

Comment: I don't have enough technical knowledge about Wi-Fi Security but I know a project which was included in Black Hat Arsenal Top 10 Security Tools announced at toolswatch. You may use PiFinger to assess security level of Wi-Fi network but you have to connect that Wi-Fi as shown on the demo video. https://github.com/toolswatch/blackhat-arsenal-tools/blob/master/network_defense/wipihunter.md . Also, you may pay attention to Wi-Fi name, password strenght, traces of unsecure https connections when connecting but all of them may be manipulated in such a way that you can not decide the security level.

Comment: What do you mean by security level? There are a lot of possible [security measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_security#Security_measures) that can be taken when configuring a wireless network. Some of them are broadcasted others are not.

Comment: @TomK I believe the OP is referring to 802.11  authentication e.g. WEP/WPA and EAP. These details can typically be obtained by a scan without requiring the modem to actually join the network, thus it is possible to scan for a network supporting a particular authentication type. All the modems I have used support this. dandavis says much the same but he talks of a micro with Wi-Fi built in rather than a dedicated modem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I do a lot with the ESP8266 micro controller, and it's API offers a wifi scan that returns the SSID, encryption type, signal strength, hidden/public, etc.
How you perform such a scan depends on software and the device, but it's possible 100%.

Doc ref: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/ESP8266WiFiScan.h#L43

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? If I'm not mistaken the infos you listed are broadcasted by most WiFis (unless you hid your SSID). Why do I need a microcontroller for this?

Comment: you don't, windows has most of the info in the built-in interface, this is just a "bird in the palm" way i know to prove a decent set of data points about non-joined networks.